# docker-compose → set wildcard domain name for linked container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dns

I have two containers: application and `MINIO` service

Let's say `docker-compose.yml` is:

```
version: "3"

services:
  s3:
    image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2021-11-09T03-21-45Z
    expose:
     - "9000"
     - "9001"
    container_name: s3
    command: server /data --console-address ":9001"
    environment:
     - MINIO_DOMAIN=s3
     - MINIO_ROOT_USER=some_user
     - MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=some_password
    healthcheck:
     test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"]
     interval: 30s
     timeout: 20s
     retries: 3
    volumes:
     - /tmp/data:/data

  app:
    image: my_image
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - s3
```

`app` container connecting to `MINIO` via `http://s3:9000` endpoint URL

When I run

```
aws --profile myprof --endpoint-url="http://s3:9000" s3 ls  s3://bucketname/path/to/file
```

all works fine.

But some of third-party libraries needed for my `app` using virtual-host styled path:

```
http://bucketname.s3:9000/path/to/file
```

And of course `bucketname.s3` can't be resolved.

I tried to set `172.19.0.4 bucketname.s3` (container local IP) inside `/etc/hosts` and all works fine. But I can't update `/etc/hosts` every time for every new bucket.

So is here any way to set wildcard hostname `*.s3` in docker?

My application use `python:3.7.0-alpine` image

Result of `cat /etc/resolv.conf`  is

```
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options edns0 ndots:0
```

So looks like it is possible to set domain inside local host resolver service by using `Dockerfile`, is here some way to do that?

#### Memo added 2022/01/25

I added network alias to `s3` container as temporary solution to be able add exact bucket names at `docker-compose up -d` timing, but that is not a solution because I still can't create new buckets on the fly without restart containers:

```
version: "3"

services:
  s3:
    image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2021-11-09T03-21-45Z
    expose:
     - "9000"
     - "9001"
    container_name: s3
    command: server /data --console-address ":9001"
    environment:
     - MINIO_DOMAIN=s3
     - MINIO_ROOT_USER=some_user
     - MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=some_password
    healthcheck:
     test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"]
     interval: 30s
     timeout: 20s
     retries: 3
    volumes:
     - /tmp/data:/data
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
         - bucketone.s3
         - buckettwo.s3
```

Also I tried to set record inside external separated DNS server:

```
*.s3  IN CNAME  s3.
```

But this way is not working too. Looks like container trying to resolve `s3.` by using same DNS server instead of use Docker internal DNS resolver (where `s3` host exists).
So looks like only possible solution is to set DNS server integrated with Docker that can manage container internal dynamic IPs and records

Answer (score 0):

(This might be not the best answer, but probably better than nothing).

I already had a custom DNS server on the host system (in my case, Acrylic). What I did as a quick fix:

1. from the depending app container: `ping anotherservice.loc` (to get the service container's IP, in my case it was 172.18.0.7)
2. on the own DNS server, added an entry `172.18.0.7 *.anotherservice.loc` and restarted the DNS
3. optionally, cleared host system DNS cache: `ipconfig /flushdns` (this command is for Windows)

In theory:

- maybe you could hardcode this IP in `docker-compose.yml`, to avoid the need to edit DNS settings, in case Docker changes it in future. Or,
- maybe you could find and set up a custom DNS server inside the depending container instead. There is some space for creativity here, I just tried to give the idea.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Most stable way is to set static internal IP for container and add permanent wildcard record to DNS server but it may cause serious problems in future. Also I really don't like to use static IPs. In case of dynamic IPs restarting DNS server every time when container is rebuilding may cause huge instability for whole service (single point of possible failure that every time restarting). Still good for development environment but not for production. So I decided to limit bucket names and add aliases to it. Probably k8s with own resolver may solve this problem.